# Matlab - Two Column Matrices into One Column Matrix with rows elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I have two column matrices:

size(X) = 50 x 1
size(Y) = 50 x 1
which I got from ind2sub

I want to create a structure str such that

```
str(i).XYZ returns [X(i), Y(i)] for i in [1,50]
```

I am trying to use

```
str = struct('XYZ', num2cell([X,Y]));
```

However, I believe for this to work properly, I need to modify [X,Y] to a matrix of row vectors, each row vector being [X(i), Y(i)]. Not sure if there is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

You are basically on the right way, but `num2cell([X,Y])` creates a 2x50 cell, which results in a 2x50 struct. You want to split your input matrix `[X,Y]` only among the second dimensions so each cell is a 2x1, use `num2cell([X,Y],2)`

```
str = struct('XYZ', num2cell([X,Y],2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the two vectors, convert from matrix to cell, and then from cell to struct array:

```
str = cell2struct(mat2cell([X Y], ones(1,size(X,1)), size(X,2)+size(Y,2) ).', 'XYZ');
```